# Using Caliper to benchmark REST Services ... or not?

Tags: rest, service, benchmarking, caliper

I want to compare the response time between different services I made. I heard about Caliper so I decided to use it in a very simple way to make calls and measure them, with some functions like that:

```
public void timeCallingService(int reps) {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/myservice/rest/"+size;
    for (int i = 0; i < reps; i++) {
        new Client(url);
    }
}
```

where size is a given parameter for Caliper and Client a class I wrote which just make a call to the service and check if the status answer is ok.

Everything's works fine except for some services which take too much time to answer, so I have an error in Caliper :

```
Error: Runtime 1.06027641E11ns/rep out of range 0.1-1.0E10
```

I tried to play with some parameters like warmupMillis and runMillis but it doesn't seem to work.

So :

1. is there any easy way to solve my problem?
2. if there isn't, which benchmark framework can I use to do my comparison, given the fact I don't want anything complicated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I apologize for that.  Caliper 0.5 has some quirks like this, but Caliper 1.0 which we're working (a) is less anal-retentive about what it expects to see when timing like this, (b) makes a lot of values configurable (such as the timing interval; you can make it longer than 1 second), and (c) also lets you plug in a different measuring instrument if the MicrobenchmarkInstrument's logic just doesn't work for you.

Unfortunately I can't promise a release date yet. :(

Comment: Ok it's fine, I finally changed the upperBound value in TimeMeasurer.java (line 81) and my benchmark seems to work well ;)

Answer (score 0):

Caliper used in TimeMeasurer.class (see source TimeMeasurer.java lines 80-84) limitations on determining of valid possible time. This limitations are lowerBound (0.1 ns) and upperBound (10 sec). That's why any longer measure than upperBound or any faster measure than lowerBound throws RuntimeOutOfRangeException. So if you really stuck on that than try to compile this class with another limit bounds, or it would be better to write to caliper author about this and suggest to add a runtime parametor about than (to set upperBound for instance). Seems (and may be the thuth is really there that) this measure tool is for measuring fast processes when the nano-seconds are impotant for the analysis. And when you measure something and it get's more than 10 sec may be you should use another measuring tool... Anyway there is a solution...